# What is /sys/devices/breakpoint device?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, linux-device-driver, breakpoints

I was looking through the files in /sys/devices/ on my Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel version 4.4.0-176-generic) and saw a device called "breakpoint".

What is this device for?

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like a hardware break point on x86.

Comment: Is this how Linux exposing hardware breakpoints to applications running in debug mode and gdb?

Comment: It's for `perf` as far as I understand.